# How to auto change iframe data after 5 minutes to another url in an array?

Tags: javascript, html, css, static

I mostly can't get the edit iframe part when the function is called. And i want it to edit the embed to a random one of the urls in the 'responses' array.

This is what i have so far:

```
<iframe id="change"></iframe>
    <script>
var changez = document.getElementById("change")
setInterval(function(){ 
       var responses = ["/radio/kfok",    "/radio/rr", "/radio/ltunes", "/radio/alt947", "/radio/v1011", "/radio/1079kiss", "/radio/937river"]
       var rand =  responses[Math.floor(Math.random() * responses.length)];
       changez.replace(rand)
}, 300000);
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. I have to add context so here is some context. This will change the station every 5 minutes and automatically choose one when the page is loaded. Here is the code:

```
    <iframe id="change" style="border:0px #ffffff none;" name="myiFrame" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" marginheight="0px" marginwidth="0px" height="100%" width="100%" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <script>
var changez = document.getElementById("change")
setInterval(function(){ 
       var responses = ["/radio/kfok",    "/radio/rr", "/radio/ltunes", "/radio/alt947", "/radio/v1011", "/radio/1079kiss", "/radio/937river", "/radio/cgr"]
       var rand =  responses[Math.floor(Math.random() * responses.length)];
       changez.src=rand
}, 300000);
        // , "/radio/"
        function start() {
                   var responses = ["/radio/kfok",    "/radio/rr", "/radio/ltunes", "/radio/alt947", "/radio/v1011", "/radio/1079kiss", "/radio/937river", "/radio/cgr"]
       var rand =  responses[Math.floor(Math.random() * responses.length)];
       changez.src=rand
        }
        start()
    </script>
```

Thanks to MonsterBasket for the base code.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
<iframe id="change"></iframe>
    <script>
        var changez = document.getElementById("change");
        (function loop() {
            var responses = ["/radio/kfok",    "/radio/rr", "/radio/ltunes", "/radio/alt947", "/radio/v1011", "/radio/1079kiss", "/radio/937river"]
            var rand =  responses[Math.floor(Math.random() * responses.length)];
            changez.src = rand;
            setTimeout(loop, 300000);
        })();
    </script>
```

This is one solution (should work!).  Wrap the whole thing in brackets to immediately invoke it, and make it a recursive function on a setTimeout instead of setInterval.

Also, the code you've referenced is old, var is not really used anymore and should be replaced with let or const: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/var-let-and-const-whats-the-difference/

Comment: var is not outdated. It is still used today. It's powerful than var or const.

Comment: I'm still learning, so you may be right, but depends on the situation right?  From what I've read it definitely seems that the common practise now is to not use var unless you really have to.  Const and let conform to lexical scoping whereas var is basically brute-forcing your var to be global no matter where you declare it, plus a few other differences.

Comment: works. but how do i make it run the function when the page is loaded?

Comment: Edited my answer.   Technically what you have is already running when the page is loaded, but you'll have to wait 5 minutes for it to do anything.

Comment: no longer works. do i need jquery?

Comment: i found a solution thanks for your help though.

Comment: Ugh, very simple fix, add the semi-colon after the first line.  My bad.
Edit: oh, all good, as long as it's working lol.